# read and display long numbers in c# from CSV

Tags: c#, csv, filestream

i have a csv file like so

**CSV FILE**

```
Peter,5.00052E+11
```

and in my c# i am reading and then displaying them like so:

**C#**

```
using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(pathFileName))
 {
    string[] cols ;
    while (sr.Peek() != -1)
    {
       cols = split(",")      
    }
      MessageBox.Show(cols[1]);
  }
```

the output i get is `5.00052E+11`
but the number that shows up in my excel is `500051882871`

i have tried converting it into double  in c# but it gives me just a bunch of zeros 
i am also fairly new to c# so any help would be appreciated

Comment: @Rufus L what is this question similar to link it please so i can have a look

Comment: It is linked, at the top of the question